# Custom sfGuard login redirect not working in symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I am using Symfony 1.4.8 and Propel as ORM. I have created a custom Sfguard login by creating a SfGuardAuth. 
I have created a login form in some pages which are not secure(i.e which are public) and want that on login, it should start a login session. 
the code that i am using,

```
$this->signin = new sfGuardFormSignin(); //creating form object
```

in view

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('@sf_guard_signin') ?>" method="post">
   <table>
       <?php echo $signin; ?>
   </table>
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and also configured app.yml in (app/frontend/modules/mymodule/config/app.yml) because i wanted this for this specific module only.

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    success_signin_url: mydashboard/index
    success_signout_url: goodbye/index
```

but on login it redirects to symfonys temporary module i.e http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/

so what can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your config in app/frontend/modules/mymodule/config/app.yml is not used because the authentication is done in sfGuardAuth module and not in your module.

Comment: so how can i do a authentication in my module??

Comment: You can extend sfGuardAuth module and override the executeSignin function. The redirect is done in it, so you can make specific redirect depending on the referer.

Comment: thank you @Lucas it helped, but still how to get referrer..i.e from which page the login was done, because depending upon that the redirections should be made.

Comment: @harish you can try in the executeSignin function `$this->getUser()->getReferer($request->getReferer())` which give you the good referer even if there was some redirect to get to login page.